# What is RSR 09TI chip?

Tags: arduino-uno

There is a chip on Arduino UNO board which I can not find anything about. It is labeled RSR 09TI. It is placed near other power related components (see the image), but what is its purpose on the board?

[image: RSR 09TI]

Comment: Looks like the power regulator from +5V to +3.3V. See [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf) component U2. Do you have a multimeter to measure the pins with regards to GND? There should be GND, +5V and +3.3V on there if I'm right.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I don't have any UNO at hand right now, but I'd guess that the 5V -> 3V3 regulator is the guy at the lower right red corner on the image (looks like smaller brother of the 20V -> 5V guy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is the dual op-amp that is used for both monitoring VIN to enable/disable the USB power, and as a buffer for the LED on pin 13.

In [the schematic](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-uno-schematic.pdf) it's U1, and is an [LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf).